# is there any way that i can get values from textbox and put it into a variable using jquery then alert it?

Tags: php, jquery, cakephp

i am trying to create a welcome page as the user types his username in a textbox. As he clicked the submit button, I would like his name to be alerted using jquery before proceeding to the next page. Here's what i got in may code:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <?php   echo $this->Html->script("jquery-1.4.3.min"); ?>

    </head>
    <body>
    <?php
        echo $content_for_layout;
    ?>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
         //       alert('JQuery is succesfully included');

        $(':submit').click(function(){
            <?php if(($this->request->controller=='members')&&($this->action=='register')):?>
                    var some = $("#myId").val();
                    alert(some);
            <?php  endif; ?>
            });

        });


    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

but it displays nothing in the alert box.

And i also tried this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <?php   echo $this->Html->script("jquery-1.4.3.min"); ?>

    </head>
    <body>
    <?php
        echo $content_for_layout;
    ?>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
         //       alert('JQuery is succesfully included');

        $(':submit').click(function(){
            <?php if(($this->request->controller=='members')&&($this->action=='register')):?>
                    //alert('well');
                    var some = $("#myId").val();
                    alert($some);
            <?php  endif; ?>
            });

        });


    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

but no alertbox pops out... and i also tried this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <?php   echo $this->Html->script("jquery-1.4.3.min"); ?>

    </head>
    <body>
    <?php
        echo $content_for_layout;
    ?>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
         //       alert('JQuery is succesfully included');

        $(':submit').click(function(){
            <?php if(($this->request->controller=='members')&&($this->action=='register')):?>
                    //alert('well');
                    var some = $("#myId").val();
                    alert($(some));
            <?php  endif; ?>
            });

        });


    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

but it gives me an alert box with [object Object] in display..  :(

what could be the right code for this?

and this is what i have in my ctp file

```
<?php
    echo $this->Form->create('Member',array('action'=>'register','id'=>'myId'));
    echo $this->Form->input('username', array('id'=>'myId'));
    echo $this->Form->end('Check');
?>
```

and this is what i get in my html source page

```
ok
```

```
<head>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-1.4.3.min.js"></script>      

</head>

<body>

<h2>REGISTER</h2>
```

Username

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {

     //       alert('JQuery is succesfully included');



    $(':submit').click(function(){

                            //alert('well');

                var some = $("#myId").val();

                //alert(some);



                    });



    });





</script>

</body>
```

Comment: Do you actually have a text box `myId` on the page?

Comment: The JQuery looks fine, are you sure you are using the correct id value? Check your html source to ensure it says `id="myId"`

Comment: <h2>REGISTER</h2>
<?php
 echo $this->Form->create('Member',array('action'=>'register','id'=>'myId'));
 echo $this->Form->input('username', array('id'=>'myId'));
 echo $this->Form->end('Check');
?>

Comment: $this->Form->input('username', array('id'=>'myId'));

Comment: that's what i have in my ctp file

Comment: Edit your question, dont post additional code in comments please. Also, have you checked for javascript console errors?

Comment: i already edited the question musefan. Nope, i did not checked for javascript console errors, i dunno how to do so as well.

Comment: @Charmie: To check for javascript errors, in Chrome, right-click > Inspect element > select "Console" tab

Comment: @Charmie it would help if you just posted the outputted html so we can see what is being generated to determine if there is an input with id= #myId

Comment: You should mark some answer as correct..

Answer (score 0):

I got it working already. Well, the id='myId' is duplicated... here's my ctp file now..

```
<h2>REGISTER</h2>
<?php
    echo $this->Form->create('Member',array('action'=>'register','id'=>'myId'));
    echo $this->Form->input('username', array('id'=>'testMe'));
    echo $this->Form->end('Check');
?>
```

and here's my default.ctp with the jquery:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <?php   echo $this->Html->script("jquery-1.4.3.min"); ?>

    </head>
    <body>
    <?php
        echo $content_for_layout;
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
         //       alert('JQuery is succesfully included');

        $(':submit').click(function(){
            <?php if(($this->request->controller=='members')&&($this->action=='register')):?>
                    //alert('well');
                    var some = $('#testMe').val();
                    //var some ='charm';
                    alert(some);
            <?php  endif; ?>
            });
        });
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did one of the other answers address this?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Script to fulfill your requirements..

```
<HTML>
    <head>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    function show_ans(myform)
    {
        var answer=myform.ans.value;    
            alert(answer);
    }

    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form onSubmit="show_ans(this)">
    <input type="text" id="ans" name="ans">
    <input type="submit">
    </form>
    </body>
    </HTML>
```

Answer (score -1):

The server side code is not generating an input element with id=myId.  You need to re-evaluate the php code to output the proper input elements like the following:

`<input type="text" id="myId" value="whatever" />`

Then this code will return the value of that input:

`$('#myId').val()`

Comment: i guess its not getting any value at all that's why it displays nothing :(

Comment: @musefan I read this on my mobile phone and must have missed the first part or it was edited.  Obviously if it was already there I deserve the downvote.

Comment: @lucuma: Not my downvotes, I was happy enough with just making my comment ;-)

Comment: @Mayankswami without the OP posting the outputted html, it would be very difficult to troubleshoot.  Assuming that there is an element on the page with  id of #myId his first example should work so I'd assume there is no element with that id or it isn't an input element.

Comment: @Mayankswami I've already acknowledged that and am waiting for more clarification from the OP.  Thanks.

Comment: guys, i updated my question. i added the html source code of the my page... pls take a look..

Comment: @Charmie I updated the answer.  There is no input being generated so you will not be able to alert or find the value.

Answer (score -1):

```
var some = $("#myId").val();
alert(some);

Or
alert($("#myId").val());
```

Comment: @Charmie: I am not asking you if you copied, I am asking the poster of this answer

Comment: i didnt even a javascript rookie knows how to alert :P

Comment: @ubercooluk: My point is, that you have suggested code that the OP has already tried, therefore can clearly not be a working answer. Even though your code is the correct use for alerting, this is obviously not the cause of the problem